# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in jsp when calling a java method whose signature has been changed

Tags: java, jsp

I have a java method with the original signature as follows:

```
public boolean sampleMethod(int num)
```

This is being called in a lot of jsp's in my project. Recently, I needed to change the method signature to:

```
public boolean sampleMethod(long num)
```

With this new signature, all the method calls in my jsp's now gives me a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError. It seems that they are still invoking the old method even if I already compiled the code. I am using Intellij IDEA 11.0.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you still have your old `war` file deployed. Do the following:

1. Stop the app/web server.
2. Delete the app from the web-apps dir.
3. Start the app/web server.
4. Deploy the new war

Comment: A new war file is being created every time I build my project.

Comment: Check that a new war is being generated and that it is copied from the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

Either overload the method or change the JSP side to explicitly call the new method. Overloaded methods will be like;

```
public boolean sampleMethod(int num){
    return sampleMethod((long) num);
}

public boolean sampleMethod(long num){
    // do your work
}
```

Comment: I did this already. But I also have a setter and getter that needs to be changed from int to long,i.e:
from: int getSamples() to long getSamples();

Comment: One more thing, the noSuchMethodError goes away whenever I make changes in the jsp like a simple println command.

Comment: You can cast to (long) in JSP also. Change getters and setters to long also.

Comment: I already changed the setters and getters to long. By the way, I just noticed that the problem is on the constants in my java class. Here's the thing. I have a constant declaration in the same java class and I also changed it from int to long, i.e.: long CONST_PARAM = 3; Then, when I access the sampleMethod in jsp, I have sampleMethod(Constants.CONST_PARAM). I noticed that Constants.CONST_PARAM is still an int when it should be a long.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Eclipse IDE.

As Reimeus said, you need to delete the EAR file.
In my case, Eclipse IDE don't store it in Tomcat folder but in `/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/` folder.

It also may be clean from Server's tab, right-click your project and choose "Clean Module Work Directory...".

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the work cache in your Servlet container and let the server recompaile all the jsp will fix.

/tomcat/work/Catalina/hostname for Tomcat